# Major difference between Apache log4cxx and log4cplus

Tags: logging, log4cxx, apr, log4cplus

I need to build my app which can make use of these c++ loggers. I am going through both the loggers(Apache log4cxx and log4cplus) I want to know the difference between the two. 1 thing which I have seen is Apache log4cxx make use of APR(Apache Portable Runtime).

So could anyone tell me the differences between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are too many differences to list here. You have already found one major difference. I suggest that you compare documentation for the classes that you are interested in. Maybe if your question was more specific, I could answer better.

**UPDATE**

I cannot think of a significant different between the two libraries in the scenario that you have described in your comment. Pretty much the only difference should be the namespace.

Comment: Thank You Wilx for replying. I have created console logger and a file logger using log4cplus. I used ConsoleAppender and FileAppender using the different Layout(TTCCLayout, PatternLayout) and I am logging various log events according to the LogLevel(DEBUG, WARN, ERROR). If I will try to Use log4cxx, then I have to use the same things.
So if I am using log4cxx and log4cplus for creating such kind of sample programs, then what would be the differences in the features of using both the loggers?